# Divide with Conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I need a formula that will divide a players contribution by the teams total contribution. So if this player plays for this team, divide his contributions by the teams contributions

Sheet 1

```
Player Name | Team Name | Player Contributions | % Share of Teams Contributions
Johnson     | Red Bulls | 14                   | Formula Needed
```

Sheet 2

```
Team Name | Team Contributions
Red Bulls       145
```

I need a formula in Sheet 1 that basically says, if Team Name in Sheet 1 = Team Name in Sheet 2, Divide the Player Contributions by that specific Teams Contributions

I'm sure its a VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH formula but unsure on how to format it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` should work:

```
=C2/(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$2,2,0))
```

Here,

- `C2` represents Player Contribution
- `B2` represents team name
- `Sheet2!$A$2:$B$2` represents LOOKUP range
- `2` represents Team contribution

**Sheet1:**

[image: Sheet1_snip]

**Sheet2:**

[image: Sheet2_snip]

***Note:*** Format the `% Share of Teams Contributions` accordingly

Comment: Yes this worked thank you!